# Permutations in matrix for subset of values in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am posting code as it would appear in my program to better illustrate the challenges I face.

```
N = 6

land_l = rep(list(0:1), N)    
land_pos = expand.grid(land_l) #gives a list of all permutations 

h = 2 # the position in land_pos of interest, here [2] 
k = list(c(2, 4, 5), c(4,5)) #representative list structure of a list of other elements

start_pos = matrix(c(0,1,1,1,0,1), nrow=1, ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)

perm_pos = matrix(start_pos, nrow = 2^length(k[[1]]), ncol = N, byrow = TRUE )
```

I now would like to alter the matrix "perm_pos" so that it reflects all possible permutations of h and k[[1]] excluding itself. That is, h = 2 and k[[1]] is 2, 4, 5. I am looking for all permutations of elements 2, 4, 5 (i.e., 0 0 0, 1 0 0, 1 1 0, and so forth while the other elements in perm_pos are kept as they are).

perm_pos should then look like this then (the order of the rows in which each unique permutation occurs is not important):

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    0    1
[2,]    0    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    0    1    1    0    0    1
[4,]    0    1    1    0    1    1
[5,]    0    0    1    1    0    1
[6,]    0    0    1    1    1    1
[7,]    0    0    1    0    0    1
[8,]    0    0    1    0    1    1
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I updated with a possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is the following.

```
tmp_l = rep(list(0:1), length(k[[1]]))    
tmp_pos = expand.grid(tmp_l)

perm_pos_adj = perm_pos
for(i in 1:nrow(tmp_pos))
{
  counter = 0
for(j in k[[1]]) 
{


  counter = counter+1
perm_pos_adj[i,j] = tmp_pos[i,counter]
}
}
```

perm_pos_adj provides the searched for results.